# How to create a loop that will display one post and stop?

Tags: php, posts, loop

I am trying to create a part on my wordpress theme that will only display one featured post. I have installed this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-post/ .

I know I am supposed to integrate `<?php query_posts($query_string."&featured=yes");` somewhere into the loop to output the featured post. I tried modifying the code from my existing loop that displays regular posts but the results show the featured post repeated many times.

This is the loop I am trying to use that displays the featured post but repeats it a ton of times. How can I get it to only display once?

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        query_posts($query_string . "&featured=yes");

        the_author();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');    
        }
?> 

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php the_excerpt();?>  
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More.... </a>   


<?php
    } // end while
} // end if                      
?>
```

Comment: Where you've added `query_posts($query_string."&featured=yes")` ?

Comment: Is it repeating the *same* featured post many times or different featured posts?

Comment: @Sumit I have edited the post to show where I added the feature function.

Comment: @engelen - It is repeating the same feature post.

Answer (score 1):

`query_posts()` can alter the WP query even when it is executed and it should be placed at least before you start the loop i.e. `have_posts()`. Currently you are placing it after setting up post data i.e. `the_post()`. Which is resulting in unexpected behavior.

**Example:**

```
global $query_string; //Get current query arguments
query_posts($query_string."&featured=yes");

if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post(); ?>    

        <? php the_author(); ?>

        <? php
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        } ?>

        <a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
        <a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More.... </a>   


        <?php
    } // end while
} // end if
```

> NOTE: `query_posts()` is not recommended please ask plugin support to
>   provide alternative way to use their plugin!

Comment: Why downvote here ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just simplified my code. Add a custom field with name "_featured" with Yes and No Radio Button and add dummy 5 posts and from which make one post to be featured to Yes and then use below code to display featured post.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => '_featured',
           'value' => 'yes'
       )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Sumit: I have added $i variable to limit the loop in my modified code.

Comment: Hi Mehul. Thanks for trying but I am still getting an error message. It only displays the one post and nothing in and it says "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in"

Comment: @Sumit: This is not that bad solution as per the details provided in the question. Also there is no argument named "featured". Please see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: @user91325: Please let us know what function you are using fetch the featured posts? Is it query_posts, get_posts or WP_Query?

Comment: @Mehul I have edited my post to show it. I am using <?php query_posts($query_string."&featured=yes"); inside of the loop to fetch the featured post.

Comment: @user91325: Check edited answer